# How i can convert the output stream using any codecs.

Tags: java

I have a project that have to stream a video in real time from the web cam or from the desctop. I think i have to convert the stream using any codecs because the output stream will be large. Any suggestions how i can convert the output stream using any codecs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

you can use ffmpeg tool for video conversion 
here is the sample command to convert a video from one codec to another 
ffmpeg  -i input.avi  -b:v 1200000 -ar 44100 -ab 180000 -s 720x400 -vcodec h264 -acodec libfdk_aac output.mp4

the above command will convert a 3gp video having 
video bitrate 120k 
audio bitrate 180k
video size 179 X 400
video codec h264 // options are available 
audio codec aac // options are available 
here is doc. [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)